# Form validation showing that fields aren't completed

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am working on a little project for myself using PHP and MySQL.

I have created a registration form that I have been filling out to test it works. I have added validation to the form to check for any empty fields, but even if I input data into every field it brings back an alert to say that not all the fields are filled in, when they clearly are.

Below is my code:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php require_once ("php/init.php"); ?>
<?php
    $user = new User();
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $user_username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $user_email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $user_firstname = trim($_POST['firstName']);
    $user_lastname = trim($_POST['lastName']);
    $user_password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $verifyPassword = trim($_POST['passwordV']);
    $user_company = trim($_POST['company']);

    $validEmail = preg_match('/^[A-z0-9_\-]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z.]{2,4}$/', $user_email);

    if ($user_username == ""
        or $user_email == ""
        or $user_firstname == ""
        or $user_lastname == ""
        or $user_password == ""
        or $verifyPassword == ""
        or $user_company == ""
    )
    {
        $message = "You have not completed all the required fields, please try again.";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        if ($validEmail)
        {
            if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['passwordV'])
            {
                $message = "The passwords that you entered do not match, please try again.";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
            }
            else
            {
                $userFound = User::locate($user_username);

                if ($userFound)
                {
                    $message = "The username entered is already being used, please Login or enter a username.";
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
                }
                else
                {
                    $user_password = User::hash($user_password);

                    $user->user_username = $user_username;
                    $user->user_email = $user_email;
                    $user->user_firstname = $user_firstname;
                    $user->user_lastname = $user_lastname;
                    $user->user_password = $user_password;
                    $user->user_company= $user_company;

                    $user->insertUser();

                    redirect("wait.php");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $message = "The email address that was entered is not in the correct format";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    $user_username = "";
    $user_email = "";
    $user_firstname = "";
    $user_lastname = "";
    $user_password = "";
    $verifyPassword = "";
    $user_company = "";
}

if (isset($_POST['back']))
{
    redirect('index.php');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Register</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="register">
            <p>Please enter the following details to register for an account.</p>
            <p>All fields are required.</p>
            <div class="input">
                <li>
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <p>
                            <label>Username:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="username">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label>Email Address:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label>First Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="firstName">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label>Last Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="lastName">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label>Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label>Re-Enter Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="passwordV">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label>Company:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Company">
                        </p>
                        </br>
                        <p><input type="submit" name="submit"></p>
                        </br>
                        <p><input type="submit" name="back" value="Back"></p>
                    </form>
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help will greatly appreciated as I am a bit stuck.

Comment: Not jumping out... Can you `var_dump` that `if` block where you check for empty?  Obviously one of those is empty... don't trust the dump of $_POST... look at exactly what your code is evaluating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="text" name="Company">` Note the capital 'C'.  The code looks for 'company' though.

`var_dump` is your friend!

I'd recommend becoming very consistent in how you write variables and the like.  I'd also, personally, look at changing your code style as far as indentation.  But at least definitely be very strict when naming things.

Comment: thank you for the information that has worked. Also thank you for the advice around my code, I am still fairly new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Check the names of the $_POST fields if are identical with this in form :).